# TSP Heuristics - Worst case ratio

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

I have some trouble trying to summarize the worst-case ratio of these heuristics for the metric (this means that it satisfies the triangle inequality) traveling salesman problem:

- Nearest neighbor
- Nearest insertion
- Cheapest insertion
- Farthest insertion

Nearest neighbor:

[Here](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~mgoetsch/cali/VEHICLE/TSP/TSP005__.HTM) it says that the NN has a w-C ratio of

[image]

[This one](http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD2440/avalg14/TSP-JohMcg97.pdf), page 8, same as [this one](https://books.google.ch/books?id=NWghN9G7q9MC&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=insertion+algorithms+worst+case+ratio&source=bl&ots=XrRjnBwtTn&sig=JjAyiMOJQRDQgVe2pWrtgz3S5Tk&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CDgQ6AEwA2oVChMIwdKukubTxwIVRAksCh3KMgC7#v=onepage&q=insertion%20algorithms%20worst%20case%20ratio&f=false) says that it is

[image]

Which changes a lot.

Insertion algorithms:
Pretty match everyone agrees that the w-c ratio for cheapest and nearest insertion is <= 2 (always just for instances satisfying the triangle inequality) but coming to the farthest insertion every source is different:

[here](http://www.mafy.lut.fi/study/DiscreteOpt/DOSLID5.pdf):

[image] (forgot to change NN to FI)

While [here](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~mgoetsch/cali/VEHICLE/TSP/TSP015__.HTM)
It is

[image]

And [here](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~goddyn/Courses/343/heuristics.pdf) there is also a different one:

[image]

Regarding the FI, I think that it depends on the starting sub-tour.
But in the NN, that *ceil* or *floor* bracket changes a lot the results, and since they all come from good sources, I can't figure out the right one.

Can someone summerize the actual known worst-case ratio for these algorithms?

Comment: Floor versus ceiling is not a material difference for most purposes. The differences for farthest are more worrying, though. Unfortunately, the only way to resolve this is to go spelunking in the TSP literature.

Comment: If I had to guess, the floor vs. ceiling thing is a typo, and the FI bounds quoted were proved in separate papers, since they're not actually in conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NN: The correct bound uses ceiling, not floor (at least as proved in the original paper by Rosenkrantz et al. -- [here](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0206041), if you have access). I don't think there's a more recent bound that uses floor.

FI: Rosenkrantz et al. prove that the first bound applies to *any* insertion heuristic, including NN. Moreover, that bound is better than the other two (except for very small n). So I would use that bound. Note, however, that `log` really means `log_2` in that formula. (I'm not sure where the other two bounds came from.)

One other note: It is known that there is **no** *fixed* worst-case bound for NN. It is **not** known whether there is a fixed worst-case bound for FI.